# Egg-Dropping Problem, with K floors and plenty of eggs

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm currently doing an exercise on algorithms, this egg question confused me:
"You have an N-floor building and plenty of eggs. Suppose that an egg is broken if it is thrown from floor F or higher, and unhurt otherwise."
A simple solution is by using binary search, which would lead to the throws of at most logN
However, "Find a new strategy to reduce the number of throws to at most 2 log F."
I saw some previous posts saying we start from 1, 2,...2^i, until we find the egg broken, and we do binary search in the smaller range of (2^i-1,2^i). I'm confused, that where do we get that TWO, and the LogN? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/puzzle-set-35-2-eggs-and-100-floors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complexity for the new strategy is log F + log F which results in 2*log F. First log F is for determining the range in which F lies which is a variation of binary search. Second log F finding the exact F using binary search in that particular range.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a perfectly clear explanation to this problem. :-)